# How to resize / re-draw Virtual Scroll in Ionic 2/3?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am currently using [VirtualScroll](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/virtual-scroll/VirtualScroll/) in my project. I am actually updating font of the list dynamically but it disturbs the size i.e height of the virtual scroll item. I want currently to resize/redraw the virtual scroll after font size change. I saw the documentation it has some instance members but i am not able to access it. So far here is how i am referencing it:

```
@ViewChild("verseList") verseList: VirtualScroll;

this.verseList.resize(); //throws error
```

It also didn't work using `nativeelement: ElementRef`. I am not sure to call these instance members:

```
 readUpdate()
 resize()
 scrollUpdate()
 setElementClass()
 writeUpdate()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just figured it out. Just like we access `Content` using `@ViewChild(Content)`, similarly we can access this too using `ViewChild`:

```
@ViewChild(VirtualScroll) verseList: VirtualScroll;
```

Make sure to import `VirtualScroll` from `ionic-angular` package at the top.